# Simple Multiply on javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to multiply priceMonthly by 30, How can I do that in this "if" function?
I am using it to echo the entered number live , but I need that number to multiply by 30.
Dose someone have over ideas,  or can someone guide me why its not working ?

```
    function keyup_fill(ele, ele_place) {
        $(ele).on("keyup", function(event) {

            if ( $(ele).attr("name") === "priceMonthly" ) {
                if (!$.isNumeric($(ele).val())) {
                    return ($(ele).val()*30); //not working
                }
            }

          var newText = event.target.value ;
            $(ele_place).html(newText); 
        });
    }


    keyup_fill("#priceMonthly", "#priceMonthly-place");
```

Comment: you must need to validate the value of text while converting to number, in case of the value is string then it causes the error. so i think you should validate first before returning,

Comment: @user706499 i have shared example with validating option as well, so please see that, hope it helps you. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

try

`return $(ele).val()*30`

multiplication should auto cast to number

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I updated my code , but I still get the same result without multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

The denial didn't make much sense

```
if ( $(ele).attr("name") === "priceMonthly" ) { 
    if ($.isNumeric($(ele).val())) {
        return ($(ele).val()*30); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ($(ele).attr("name") === "priceMonthly") {
  if (Number($(ele).val()) !== NaN) {
    return ($(ele).val() * 30);
  } else {
    return "value is not number";
  }
}
```